# Why does SignedAngle work properly with transform.position but not with transform.localPosition?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a VR motorcycle game and trying to get the steering to work by the player grabbing and rotating the handles. The steering works because of the function `CalculateRotation()` (in the code block below) which gets the angle between the hands and rotates the handlebars/the bike based on that.

When `transform.position` is used for the controller positions it works smoothly (the handlebars smoothly rotate to the controller positions), but when `transform.localPosition` is used it freaks out (the handlebars rotate away from the controller positions as far as they can - 50degrees because the `maxRotation` variable clamps the rotation to 50degrees) so you can't actually grab onto the handlebars.

I would just use `position` but when the bike starts moving it can't calculate the angle properly and the handlebars start acting like they do with `localPosition`.

I either need to figure out why `localPosition` doesn't work or figure out how to make `position` work when the bike is moving. But I would like to have some insight on why `localPosition` isn't working since if I can figure out why it's an issue I can likely solve it.

Some more info:
I tried using `transform.TransformDirection`/`TransformPoint`/`TransformVector` & the inverses but they didn't seem to help. Also the handlebars and the controllers are children of different `gameobjects` so I think that may be a part of why the `localPosition` doesn't work but I'm not sure. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[Here's a link of it working with position then not working with localPosition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXH98.jpg)

```
private Quaternion CalculateRotation()
    {
 
        //hand xz + source y (to stay consistent)
        //use these positions to figure out do the math for rotation
        //USE POSITION NOT LOCALPOSITION FOR IT TO WORK
 
 
        /*leftControllerPos = leftController.transform.InverseTransformDirection(leftController.transform.position);
        rightControllerPos = rightController.transform.InverseTransformDirection(rightController.transform.position);
        leftSubPos = leftSub.transform.InverseTransformDirection(leftSub.transform.position);
        rightSubPos = rightSub.transform.InverseTransformDirection(rightSub.transform.position);*/
 
        leftControllerPos = leftController.transform.position;
        rightControllerPos = rightController.transform.position;
        leftSubPos = leftSub.transform.position;
        rightSubPos = rightSub.transform.position;
 
        //check which hands are detected to get targetDir
        Vector3 firstPos;
        Vector3 secondPos;
        if (detectedHands == DetectedHands.BothHands)
        {
            Debug.Log("BothHands");
            firstPos = leftControllerPos;
            secondPos = rightControllerPos;
            Debug.Log("firstPos = " + firstPos + "\nsecondPos = " + secondPos);
        }
        else if (detectedHands == DetectedHands.LeftHandOnly)
        {
            Debug.Log("LeftHandOnly");
            firstPos = leftControllerPos;
            secondPos = rightSubPos;
        }
        else if (detectedHands == DetectedHands.RightHandOnly)
        {
            Debug.Log("RightHandOnly");
            firstPos = leftSubPos;
            secondPos = rightControllerPos;
            Debug.Log("firstPos = " + firstPos + "\nsecondPos = " + secondPos);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("None");
            firstPos = leftControllerPos;
            secondPos = rightControllerPos;
        }
 
        //do math with correct targetDir
        Vector3 targetDir = secondPos - firstPos;
        Vector3 right = transform.right;
 
        float angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(targetDir, right, Vector3.up);
 
        angle = Mathf.Clamp(angle, -maxRotation, +maxRotation);
        AdjustedAngle = -angle;
 
       
 
        //visualizeDirection.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, -angle, 0));
        //Quaternion bikeRotation = FindObjectOfType<BikeController>().transform.localRotation;
        Quaternion firstRot = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(-24, 0, 0));
        Quaternion secondRot = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, AdjustedAngle, 0));
        Quaternion adjustedRotation = firstRot * secondRot; //bikeRotation *
        Debug.Log("adjustedRotation = " + adjustedRotation);
        return adjustedRotation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of [`InverseTransformDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html) you would rather want to use [`InverseTransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html)!

From the API

> You should use `Transform.InverseTransformPoint` if the vector represents a position in space rather than a direction.

You are currently treating some world space positions as if they were directions - this is only valid for the world origin `0,0,0` ;)

Further it makes no sense to convert each individual object position into it's own local space ... the result would always be `0,0,0`!

**If** you want to calculate in local space of an object it would always need to be the **same** objects local space!

So since you later compare to **this** object's `transform.right` probably

```
    leftControllerPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(leftController.transform.position);
    rightControllerPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(rightController.transform.position);
    leftSubPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(leftSub.transform.position);
    rightSubPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(rightSub.transform.position);
```

Then later when you come to the `SignedAngle` you would also have to use accordingly [`Vector3.right`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-right.html) instead of the world space vector [`transform.right`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-right.html) in order to use local space.

Facit: If world space positions works then why bother around with local space positions?